# does socket buffer occupy process memory address?

Tags: networking, virtual-memory, socket

As we know, we can use `setsocketopt` api to alter the socket's buffer size.

Since the socket fd is created by user process, does it occupy process memory address, like the top 1G kernal space in each
process 4G virtual address for 32-bit machine?

And when socket is closed, it seems that the fd is not released until 2MSL time elapsed, which will cause the buffer to exist for longer time.

To clarify, my question is: Is the socket buffer mapped to the user virtual address space of the process?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what your asking.  Is your question _Is the socket buffer mapped to the user virtual address space of the process?_  If so, then no.

Comment: @AndyDalton That's it. Because afaik, each processes' address space contains 1G kernel space. So I was wondering if the socket buffer is mapped to that kernel space of each process.